# New environment with dedicated index and reference

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, numbering, environments

I'm using `chemfig` to create some structural formulas, but I need to create a new environment, like equation, that have a dedicated index and reference counter. I'm searching about this, but I'm having some difficult to get something that works for me.

For example, I would like somenthing like:

```
text text text text~\ref{eq:foo} 

\begin{equation}
    a = b
    \label{eq:foo}
\end{equation}

text text text text~\ref{sf:foo}   

\begin{structuralFormula}
    H_{2}O
    \label{sf:foo}
\end{structuralFormula}

text text text text~\ref{eq:bar} 

\begin{equation}
    h^2 = c_1^2 + c_2^2
    \label{eq:bar}
\end{equation}

text text text text~\ref{sf:bar} 

\begin{structuralFormula}
    \chemfig{
        C(
        -[:0]H
        )(
        -[:90]H
        )(
        -[:180]H
        )(
        -[:270]H
        )
    }
    \label{sf:bar}
\end{structuralFormula}
```

[image]

I.e., I need a new environment, that works exactly like equation and that have a new index entry, dedicated only to this new environment. I calling the numbers as index entry, but I realy don't know if this is the correct technical name.

I already have something like this:

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
    openright,          % capítulos começam em pág ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)
    twoside,            % para impressão em verso e anverso. Oposto a oneside
    a4paper,            % tamanho do papel. 
    chapter=TITLE,      % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    section=TITLE,      % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    english,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
    french,             % idioma adicional para hifenização
    spanish,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
    brazil,             % o último idioma é o principal do documento
]{abntex2}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lastpage}   
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}      
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,        
    linkcolor=black,        
    citecolor=black,        
    filecolor=black,        
    urlcolor=black,
    bookmarksdepth=4
}
\makeatother



\NewEnviron{structuralFormula}{%
    \begin{equation}
    \BODY
    \end{equation}
}



\begin{document}

    text text text text~\ref{eq:foo} 

    \begin{equation}
        a = b
        \label{eq:foo}
    \end{equation}

    text text text text~\ref{sf:foo}  

    \begin{structuralFormula}
        H_{2}O
        \label{sf:foo}
    \end{structuralFormula}

    text text text text~\ref{eq:bar} 

    \begin{equation}
    h^2 = c_1^2 + c_2^2
    \label{eq:bar}
    \end{equation}

    text text text text~\ref{sf:bar}

    \begin{structuralFormula}
        \chemfig{
            C(
            -[:0]H
            )(
            -[:90]H
            )(
            -[:180]H
            )(
            -[:270]H
            )
        }
        \label{sf:bar}
    \end{structuralFormula}

\end{document}
```

That generates this:

[image]

But I want the numbers like the first picture.

Comment: Please post a compilable document, not only fragments. With index you mean something like a `\listofstructuralformula`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Done. A way to make a list would be nice, but I need separate numbers for equation and the new environment. Take a look now, with my document. I post the result too.

Comment: not meaning to be discouraging, but won't using the same numbers for both be confusing to a reader?  (maybe using a prefix for one or the other would be useful in that respect.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: That's a good idea. I think, I will rework my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A preliminary version with `article` instead of `abntex2` (that one fails!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{environ}



\newcommand{\listofstructformname}{List of structural formulas}

\newlistof{structform}{stf}{\listofstructformname}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{structuralFormula}[1]{%
  \let\c@equation\c@structform
  \renewcommand{\theHequation}{structform.\theequation}
  \begin{equation}
    \BODY
    \addcontentsline{stf}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}
  }[%
\end{equation}
]
\makeatother


\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks=true,        
    linkcolor=black,        
    citecolor=black,        
    filecolor=black,        
    urlcolor=black,
    bookmarksdepth=4
}



\begin{document}
\listofstructform

\clearpage
text text text text~\ref{eq:foo} 

\begin{equation}
    a = b
    \label{eq:foo}
\end{equation}

text text text text~\ref{sf:foo}   

\begin{structuralFormula}{Water}
    H_{2}O
    \label{sf:foo}
\end{structuralFormula}

text text text text~\ref{eq:bar} 

\begin{equation}
    h^2 = c_1^2 + c_2^2
    \label{eq:bar}
\end{equation}

text text text text~\ref{sf:bar} 

\begin{structuralFormula}{Something I don't know}
    \chemfig{
        C(
        -[:0]H
        )(
        -[:90]H
        )(
        -[:180]H
        )(
        -[:270]H
        )
    }
    \label{sf:bar}
\end{structuralFormula}

\end{document}
```

**Update** Due to the pecularities of `abntex2` (it's based on `memoir`), the easy setup with `tocloft` does not work -- the list has to be setup manually.

```
\documentclass[
12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
openright,          % capítulos começam em pág ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)
twoside,            % para impressão em verso e anverso. Oposto a oneside
a4paper,            % tamanho do papel. 
chapter=TITLE,      % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
section=TITLE,      % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
english,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
french,             % idioma adicional para hifenização
spanish,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
brazil,             % o último idioma é o principal do documento
]{abntex2}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lastpage}   
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}      
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}



\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{environ}



\newcommand{\listofstructformname}{List of structural formulas}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{structform}
\newcommand{\listofstructform}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\contentsname\listofstructformname
  \let\latex@@starttoc\@starttoc
  \def\@starttoc##1{\latex@@starttoc{stf}}
  \tableofcontents
  \endgroup
}

\NewEnviron{structuralFormula}[1]{%
  \let\c@equation\c@structform
  \renewcommand{\theHequation}{structform.\theequation}% Make hyperref happy!
  \renewcommand{\@currentlabelname}{#1}% Make nameref working
  \begin{equation}
    \BODY
    \addcontentsline{stf}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}
  }[%
\end{equation}
]
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks=true,        
    linkcolor=black,        
    citecolor=black,        
    filecolor=black,        
    urlcolor=black,
    bookmarksdepth=4
}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listofstructform

\clearpage
text text text text~\ref{eq:foo} 

\begin{equation}
    a = b
    \label{eq:foo}
\end{equation}

text text text text~\ref{sf:foo}   

\begin{structuralFormula}{Water}
    H_{2}O
    \label{sf:foo}
\end{structuralFormula}

text text text text~\ref{eq:bar} 

\begin{equation}
    h^2 = c_1^2 + c_2^2
    \label{eq:bar}
\end{equation}

text text text text~\ref{sf:bar} 

\begin{structuralFormula}{Something I don't know}
    \chemfig{
        C(
        -[:0]H
        )(
        -[:90]H
        )(
        -[:180]H
        )(
        -[:270]H
        )
    }
    \label{sf:bar}
\end{structuralFormula}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: @davidbuzatto: You're welcome! Happy TeXing!

Comment: `memoir` has `\newlistof`

Comment: @egreg: I know, but compiling with `abntex2` reports `\listofstructform` to be unknown then.